# Is there something I need to do to get MonoDevelop's "Go to Definition" to work properly?

Tags: monodevelop

I have this line of code in a .cs file:

```
_contextOwner.AsyncLoadings.Add(Application.LoadLevelAdditiveAsync(_sceneNames[i]));
```

If I select _contextOwner, I can right-click and do "Go to Definition" to jump to the code where it is defined.

If I select AsyncLoadings, the "Go to Definition" option is not in the right-click menu. If I hover the pointer on it, it shows a tooltip with its type, so it does recognize the definition.

I'm using MonoDevelop version 4.0.1, which is attached to the version of Unity we are using.

According to this:

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/189091/mono-go-to-declaration-missing.html

The problem existed in MD 2.4.2 a few years ago. I would be surprised if it were not fixed in that time... maybe this is a Unity issue?

Comment: monodevelop 4.0.x is very old, please upgrade to a new version

Comment: We have to use whatever monodevelop version comes with Unity.

Comment: that's not true, I think some unity devs are using latest Xamarin Studio with some plugin